# AutoMapper Entity to DTO got eror: has no key defined.Define the key for this EntityType(DTO)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, automapper, poco

I have a problem with AutoMapper between DTO class and Entity model. I used POCO generator to create Entity, after that i use autoMapper to map Entity to DTO, but i got an error like this:

```
Treasury.Model.EntityDTO: : EntityType 'EntityDTO' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

I used some DTO in the partial class of Entity model.

Please help me solve the problem.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you added EntityDTO to the DbContext as a DbSet property, but if this is the Dto and not the actual entity, you don't want that on DbContext.

If this is supposed to be the actual Entity, then you need to add the [Key] attribute to the PK or assign it via FluentAPI mapping.  If you don't have a PK on your table, you need to add one or EF won't work for you.

Comment: @ Lorenz: I don't use DTO in dbContext ,

Comment: In your Entity model, you need to have the [Key] attribute on the property that is the primary key.  If your table in the database does not have a primary key, you will get this error. EF requires a PK to work.  Maybe you could post the Entity that was generated.

Comment: @ Lorenz. Thank for your help. I solved the problem  with use NotMapped  annotation for Partial class property.